# Passing data between iPhone apps

Tags: iphone

Disclaimer: This is a specific request by a client. I can't see how what I'm asking is possible, but I figured this community could give me a definitive answer.

Is there a way to pass data between iPhone apps that are not in the same app suite? I understand that apps in the same app suite that use the same App ID can pass data via a shared data store, and that apps that leverage custom URLs can pass data through parameters.

I am looking for a way to use an existing third-party app through my own app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one thing if you control both apps. If not, it really depends. I can only imagine two ways to exchange data which Apple will approve:

1. contact the developers of the third-party app and try to convince them to implement some URL exchange mechanism;
2. tell your client to use copy-paste.

I know some people simply refuse to understand what an application sandbox is, so the option 2 may be unrealistic. Do you really have to pass data in both ways? If the third-party app is a web service client, there may be a way to contact the web service directly. Otherwise, I'm afraid, you're out of luck.